# Access Violation when using SetLength()

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm writing a connect4 game using Pascal for an assignment. It would by default create a board with the size of 6x7 and win length equal 4, however it can also be passed parameters such as `./connect4 9x9 5` will create a board size 9 by 9 and win length to 5. Here is a short example of how I am writing it:

```
program Connect4;
uses SysUtils,crt;
const
  Rows = 6;
  Columns = 7;
  Symbols: array[0..2] of char = ('.', '1', '2');
  boardHead: array[0..25] of char = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

type
  TBoard = array of array of integer;

var
  Board: TBoard;
  CurrentPlayer: integer;
  WinSize: integer;

procedure PlayGame;
var
  input: char;
  column, row, turn, g: integer;
  gameOver: boolean;
  {for customize board}
  param, rowsStr, colsStr: string;
  xPos, rows, cols: integer;
begin
{experiment customize board}
if ParamCount > 1 then
begin
  param := ParamStr(1);

  // find the position of the 'x' character in the parameter
  xPos := Pos('x', param);

  // extract the substrings before and after the 'x' character
  rowsStr := Copy(param, 1, xPos - 1);
  colsStr := Copy(param, xPos + 1, Length(param) - xPos);

  // convert the substrings to integers
  Val(rowsStr, rows, xPos);
  Val(colsStr, cols, xPos);

  WinSize :=  StrToInt(ParamStr(2)); 
  SetLength(Board,rows);

  for g := 0 to rows-1 do
    SetLength(Board[g], cols);
  
end
else
begin
  SetLength(Board, Rows);
  for g := 0 to rows-1 do
    SetLength(Board[g], cols);
  WinSize := 4;
  
end;
```

Using the FreePascal compiler, it compiled at first, but when I run default it just displays:

```
A B C D E F G 
An unhandled exception occurred at $00000001006F3C80:
                                                     EAccessViolation: Access violation
                                                                                         $00000001006F3C80
                                                                                                            $00000001006F47A0
```

Does anyone know what causes this error?

I tried to seperate the allocation of memory into `setlegth(Board, row)`, `setlegth(Board[i], columns)` but it still has the same error.

Is there something I missed, or probably the code works differently on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

`PlayGame()` has a local variable `rows` that *shadows* the global constant `Rows`.

In the default case, the *local* `rows` and `cols` variables are not being assigned values, but are still being used in `SetLength()`. You meant to use the global `Rows` and `Columns` instead.

I would suggest moving the `SetLength()` calls out of the `if..else` block entirely, and use the global constants to initialize the local variables, eg

```
program Connect4;

uses
  SysUtils, crt;

const
  cRows = 6;
  cColumns = 7;
  cWinSize = 4;
  ...

type
  TBoard = array of array of integer;

var
  Board: TBoard;
  ...
  WinSize: integer;

procedure PlayGame;
var
  ..., g: integer;
  ...
  param, rowsStr, colsStr: string;
  xPos, rows, cols: integer;
begin
  {experiment customize board}
  if ParamCount > 1 then
  begin
    param := ParamStr(1);

    // find the position of the 'x' character in the parameter
    xPos := Pos('x', param);

    // extract the substrings before and after the 'x' character
    rowsStr := Copy(param, 1, xPos - 1);
    colsStr := Copy(param, xPos + 1, MaxInt);

    // convert the substrings to integers
    rows := StrToInt(rowsStr);
    cols := StrToInt(colsStr);

    WinSize := StrToInt(ParamStr(2));
  end else
  begin
    rows := cRows;
    cols := cColumns;
    WinSize := cWinSize;
  end;

  SetLength(Board, rows);
  for g := 0 to rows-1 do
    SetLength(Board[g], cols);
  
  ...
  
end;
```